# How to reposition botton inside card grid bootstrap 5?

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5

Currently, I'm trying to use Bootstrap 5 card grid system as part of my dashboard.

I found an issue when it's getting resize. I put both of div inside a row. I expect when the size is enough, they will remain in a line (since there still space on it )

Default position :
[image: defaultsize]

Getting Resize
[image]

This is how i create the div

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="row g-0">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
                    <label>label1</label>
                    <h3>label2</h3>
                    <label class="subField">awdadad@asdad.sadad</label>
                    <a href="#">Resend<span>></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-center">
                <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:fit-content">Verified</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to make it as a row when space is enough. I know `col-md-8` will make his width 100%. But can you share how to solve it?

Comment: I believe you should replace the `col-md-8` to `col-8` and `col-md-4` to `col-4`. Then make sure to add `align-items-end` for the `card-body`.